# Column break and beginning two new columns on same page

Tags: two-column

I am new to LaTeX, so please bear with me if my question does not meet the requirements, or if the solution is obvious.

I am creating a document with two colums, and after my text, I want some kind of break, so my references begin in the left column. So to speak, I want a *new page*, just beginning at the same page as the text. I hope it makes sense. I would prefer if I could do it without any additional packages, but please let me know if I have to install one to make it work. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,twocolumn,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{natbib} 

\begin{document}

Bla bla 

\newpage

Bla Bla

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{/Users/Nikolaj/Documents/Samf/library}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just discovered another way of doing something a bit like this. By simply using the package `flushend`, the columns on the last page will have the same size. Flushend is a part of the `ttools` package that can be found in the MikTex Package Manager.
Of course, this does not make the break as I asked for in the original post, but it does something close to :-)

Comment: And it seems flushend is not very good. The package balance is much better when I use the automatic bibliography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of a solution is to close the current two column mode, and the start a new one. You need to use the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package for that purpose.

I failed to solve the problem when you use a global two column mode.

---

In this example, [`lipsum`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lipsum/lipsum.pdf) and [`xampl`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/xampl.bib) are for dummy texts and bibliographies only.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1]
  \nocite{*}
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{xampl}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

---

Here is the output.

[image]

Comment: @Nikolaj Glad to be of assistance. You can upvote the answer as well. :-)

Comment: I will do this as soon as I get 15 reputation :-)